# Get data in browser from return statement

Tags: php, arrays, linux, return

I have this easy PHP script:

```
<?php 

    return array (
        'information' => array (
            'key' => 'value'
        );
    );  

?>
```

When I call this script in the browser, there is a clear HTML page. This is quite normal.

Is there any way to catch this array and read it in the browser?
For example with console(firebug) or kali linux etc?

Comment: Since you don't send it to the client how should you be able to see it?

Comment: isnt it sent to the client when i return an array with php?

Comment: cause when i var_dump it, it is displayed on the page, but is there no possibilty to read it throught the http Response etc.. ?

Comment: `var_dump()` prints data  and with that it sends it to the client; No only with a return statement you can't send data to the client

Comment: (BTW: Just to have it said: I'm assuming that the inner semicolon is a typo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [return statement](http://php.net/return) is entirely internal to PHP, it is not visible to any other process. In the context you've used it, the argument is simply ignored. There would be no way for anything other than PHP to understand something like an array anyway, as that is a data structure unique to the PHP runtime engine.

The main "result" of a PHP script (in a web server context) is its output, which is passed via the web server to the browser at the other end of the connection. You can also influence the HTTP headers the web server will include, using the [`header()`](http://php.net/header) function.

To output data for use elsewhere, you need to come up with a string representation. The easiest is probably to use `echo json_encode($value);`

Answer (score 1):

No, return doesn't send the data to the client. If you do a return statement in global scope you end the script. You can also read more about [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) in the manual.

And a quote from there:

> If called from the **global scop**e, then **execution of the current script file is ended**. If the current script file was included or required, then control is passed back to the calling file.

Comment: so there is no possibilty to catch this information?

Comment: @alkilinux Only with this script and the return statement no. You don't send anything to the client, you just stop the script execution.